# How to add/remove nodes to React Tree View

Tags: reactjs, dynamic, tree, treeview, react-d3

I want to create a tree that allows the user to be able to add/remove nodes by clicking on the node that the user would like to add children to/remove the node they click on. I am using the react-expendable-treeview package as I like how it looks visually. Javascript functionality can be found under src/lib/components/

The github repo can be found here: https://github.com/fosco/react-expandable-treeview and the tree looks like so: https://i.stack.imgur.com/C7BZp.jpg

The data that is passed into the TreeView component is predefined in a javascript file like so:

```
const testData = [
{
    id: 0,
    name: "Felidae",
    children: [
        {
            id: 1,
            name: "Pantherinae",
            children: [
                {
                    id: 2,
                    name: "Neofelis",
                },
                {
                    id: 3,
                    name: "Panthera",
                }
            ]
        },
        {
```

I'm wondering how I can set this up so I am able to add/remove children. I am aware that there are many other react tree packages such as react-d3-tree. However, I visually like how this one looks. If anyone knows how I can modify this package or change the theme of react-d3-tree or another package to look like this, please let me know.

Comment: Did you resolve this?